# how to disable double click rename in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When I double click a file, sometimes it will not open the file but turns into rename prompt. How can we disable this function? I have set my mouse-double-click-speed to the slowest side, but I still get this problem quite frequently. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to disable it, but you might want to try either of these:

- Enable single click to open (inside any folder click the View tab >
  Options > Single click to open an item).
- Double click on the icon or other list categories if you have it set like that, just not the name.
- Simply press enter if you already have the file selected

For a more involved solution, and if you're comfortable with it, you can cook up a mouse chording script in autohotkey or autoit that either double clicks fast or presses enter when you hold down both mouse buttons.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a resolution to this annoying "feature", you can change the following values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel` from the DOS command prompt to prevent Windows (all versions I've tested it against) from going into `rename` mode when you double-click on a directory or filename in the Desktop Explorer.

```
@REM Fix mouse drag width/height and most autoscrolling
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v DragWidth /d 64 /t REG_SZ /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v DragHeight /d 64 /t REG_SZ /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WheelScrollChars /d 0 /t REG_SZ /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WheelScrollLines /d 3 /t REG_SZ /f

@REM Prevent double-click going into "Rename" mode
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /v DoubleClickHeight /d 24 /t REG_SZ /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /v DoubleClickSpeed /d 270 /t REG_SZ /f
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse" /v DoubleClickWidth /d 400 /t REG_SZ /f
```

Does it work 100% of the time?  Of course not -- especially if your double-click is excruciatingly slow.  But the vast majority of the time it does bypass that idiotic `rename` functionality that Microsoft has refused to fix for the past 30 years.

Answer (score -1):

Click the icon instead or use the keyboard to work with the arrow keys and Enter.